# Building android project with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Im trying to build a simple android app using gradle build tools. but im getting an error like this

No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT]
  Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)

ang here's a simple configuration of build.gradle

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    compile 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT'
  }
}


apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
} 


processResource {
    expand (project.properties)
}

task configureDebug << {
    jar.classifier = "debug"
}

task configureRelease << {
    proguard.enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When applying a plugin you want tell you build script to use it in its classpath. It is not required for compilation so just change the configuration `compile` to `classpath`. More more information see [51.5.1. Using your plugin in another project](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) in the Gradle user guide.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-android-plugin:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** At the moment the plugin does not support r20 of the Android SDK. For more information see this [issue](https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin/issues/65).

Comment: I change the compile to classpath but im still getting an error on build. and its pointing to. apply plugin : 'android' FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file '/home/user/workspace/ImageSdcard/build.gradle' line: 16 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ProjectName'. > assert toolsDir.exists() | | | false /home/user/android-sdk-linux /tools

Comment: Please run it with the `-s` flag on the command line and post the stack trace.

Comment: I try to run gradle -s build and i get the following exception here's the log. here's the log on the link [error.log](http://pastie.org/4397194)

Comment: Looks to me as if you did not set your `sdk.dir` correctly in `local.properties`. Did you intend to have a space in that path? And if yes does the directory `/home/user/android-sdk-linux /tools` exist?

Comment: Ive already set local.properties to sdk.dir=/home/user/android-sdk-linux and still have the same error. I would like to ask if the android r20 sdk is fully supported on this plugin?

Comment: The code checks if there's a `tools` directory under the directory you set as `sdk.dir`. Here's the [code](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-android-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/jvoegele/gradle/plugins/android/AndroidSetupFactory.groovy#L34). So as long as `/home/user/android-sdk-linux/tools` doesn't exist an error would be thrown. I think you would be better off asking this on the [GitHub page of the plugin](https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin/issues).

Comment: Not sure if you saw my edit. r20 is not supported. See my comment above.

Comment: the problem on the r20 is the NewSetupTask.class is missing inside that anttask.jar, is there any work around to build the app using r20?

Comment: I'd say add a comment to the issue on GitHub or submit a pull request to the plugin if you know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are writing the dependency block on your application build.gradle "YourProjectName->yourprojectname->build.gradle" in android studio hierarchy .

Answer (score 0):

Use android gradle tools

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
}
```